# pass json config variable to a function in jsonnet

Tags: json, jsonnet

I had a jsonnet file where there is a file `config.json` which is hard coded in the variable. What I want to do is to have the ability to pass config_v1.json or config.v*.json as an argument to the config. How do I do that in the jsonnet ?

```
local config(
   args,
   resources,
   nodeAffinity,
   replicas=1,
   ttl='',
   fullName=naming.NewFullName('allm', namespace),
   image=naming.WithRegistry('allm:' + env.global.User + '-latest'),
   routes=null,
   command=null,
       ) = (
   local configMap = {
     apiVersion: 'v1',
     kind: 'ConfigMap',
     metadata: {
       name: fullName.name,
       namespace: fullName.namespace,
       labels: { app: fullName.name },
     },
     data: {
       'conf-multiturn.json': std.manifestJsonEx(confData, '  '),
     },
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want the configData JSON to be verbatim manifested, you really don't need to manipulate it further.

In the below example, I use `importstr` to load `configdata.json` as-is, then build two data fields: one verbatim from loaded JSON, then another one with one of its fields changed via jsonnet just to show you how the possible transformations should be done (*not* needed in your original use case):

### foo.jsonnet

```jsonnet
local confData = importstr 'configdata.json';

local config(confData) = (
  local configMap = {
    apiVersion: 'v1',
    kind: 'ConfigMap',
    metadata: {
      name: 'myname',
      namespace: 'mynamespace',
      labels: { app: 'myname' },
    },
    // data fields need to be: { key: value }, both as strings
    data: {
      // verbatim JSON manifested as string
      'confData.json': confData,
      // original JSON parsed into jsonnet object, modified, then manifested as string
      'confData2.json': std.manifestJson(
        std.parseJson(confData) { foo: 'otherBar' }
      ),
    },
  };
  configMap
);

config(confData)
```

### configdata.json

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "qqq": "qux"
}
```

### output

```shell
$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet | jq -r '.data["confData.json"]' 
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "qqq": "qux"
}

$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet | jq -r '.data["confData2.json"]'
{
    "foo": "otherBar",
    "qqq": "qux"
}

$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet | kubeconform -verbose
stdin - ConfigMap myname is valid
```